# Al dar Clic en un Linkbutton dentro de un GridView, OnRowCommand no se ejecuta

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Buen día a todos.
Tengo la siguiente problemática. Estoy haciendo una práctica en Asp.net con C#. En el cual despliego un `GridView` con datos y dentro de este añado un `LinkButton` en la primer columna. Al momento de dar click a cualquiera de ellos el `LinkButton` desaparece y no hace nada. Al momento de depurar mi código no entra a la función `gdvRevision_RowCommand`

Este es codigo de C#.

```
using ClasesNucleo;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NotificacionesV1._1.Boletas
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        #region Atributos
        //Atributo que almacena el nombre de la variabre de sesion para el GridView con el resumen
        private readonly string _gdvRevisionNombre = "gdvRevision";
        private readonly string _nombreSesionDetalle = "gdvViajes";
        #endregion



        protected void ddlFilas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Guarda la cantidad de filas a mostrar
            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).Filas = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFilas.SelectedValue);
            //Actualiza el GridView
            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).ActualizarGdv(gdvRevision, "PROPED");


        }

        protected void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Busca cadenas coincidentes en el DataTable de la sesión
            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).BuscarEnColumna(ddlColumnas.SelectedValue, txtBuscar.Text);
            // Actualiza la vista del GridView Resumen
            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).ActualizarGdv(gdvRevision, "PROPED");
            //Muestra mensaje con la cantidad de registros encontrados
            lblRegistros.Text = ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).Mensaje_registros_encotrados;
        }

        protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Exporta el DataTable de resumen a excel
            var dt = ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).Dt;

            HerramientasASP.ExportarExcelWeb(dt, $"Reporte Boletas");
        }

        protected void gdvRevision_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).CambiarPagina(sender, e);
        }

        protected void gdvRevision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void gdvRevision_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).OrdenarColumna(sender, e);
        }

        protected void bntConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOperador.Text))
            {
                //Limpia la variable de sesion
                Session[_gdvRevisionNombre] = null;
                // Inicializa la configuración del GridView Resumen en la variable de sesión
                ConfigurarGvResumen();
                if (Session[_gdvRevisionNombre] != null)
                    // Actualiza la vista del GridView Resumen
                    ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).ActualizarGdv(gdvRevision);
                //HabilitaControles();

                PanelResumen.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                labelError.CssClass = "text-danger";
                labelError.Text = "Ingrese un operador valido";
            }
        }

        protected void gdvRevision_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewConfig objGridDetalle = ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]);

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (objGridDetalle.PosicionColumna(i) == "PRQPED")
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(HerramientasASP.CrearLinkButton(e.Row.Cells[i].Text, e.Row.RowIndex.ToString(), ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).PosicionColumna(i), false, "", Color.Green));

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void gdvRevision_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {


            //validamos si el command argument es una filo
            if (Int32.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out int fila) && fila < gdvRevision.Rows.Count)
            {
                string id = gdvRevision.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[0].ToString();
                //ViewState["Pedido"] = id;

                //Session[_nombreSesionDetalle] = null;


                ConfiguraGdvViaje(Convert.ToInt32(id));

                if (Session[_nombreSesionDetalle] != null)
                {
                    ((GridViewConfig)Session[_nombreSesionDetalle]).ActualizarGdv(gdvViajes, "PEMSTS");
                }

                panelViajes.Visible = true;
            }
        }




        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                ListItem i;
                i = new ListItem("Enero", "1");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Febrero", "2");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Marzo", "3");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Abril", "4");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Mayo", "5");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Junio", "6");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Julio", "7");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Agosto", "8");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Septiembre", "9");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Octubre", "10");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Noviembre", "11");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);
                i = new ListItem("Diciembre", "12");
                ddlMes.Items.Add(i);

                ListItem x;
                x = new ListItem("2021", "2021");
                ddlAnio.Items.Add(x);
                x = new ListItem("2022", "2022");
                ddlAnio.Items.Add(x);
                x = new ListItem("2023", "2023");
                ddlAnio.Items.Add(x);



                PanelResumen.Visible = false;
                panelViajes.Visible = false;

                InicializaControles();
            }
            else
            {
                if (Session[_nombreSesionDetalle] != null)
                {
                    ((GridViewConfig)Session[_nombreSesionDetalle]).ActualizarGdv(gdvRevision);
                }
            }




        }

        private void InicializaControles()
        {
            panelViajes.Visible = Session[_nombreSesionDetalle] != null && ((GridViewConfig)Session[_nombreSesionDetalle]).Dt.Rows.Count > 0;
        }



        private void ConfiguraGdvViaje(int id)
        {
           

            Session[_nombreSesionDetalle] = new GridViewConfig()
            {
                Dt = ClasesNucleo.TMS.Boletas.Boletas.ObtenerDatosViajePorPedido(id),
                Indice = 0,

            };

            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_nombreSesionDetalle]).ActualizarGdv(gdvViajes);

        }



        #region Metodos propios
        private void ConfigurarGvResumen()
        {
            HerramientaDropDownList.LlenarDropDownList(ddlFilas, Catalogo.DtCatalogo(Catalogo.General.VistaAmpliaGridView));

            // Instancia configuración y asigna en sesión
            Session[_gdvRevisionNombre] = new GridViewConfig
            {
                Dt = ClasesNucleo.TMS.Boletas.Boletas.ObtenerPedidosPorOperador(Convert.ToInt32(txtOperador.Text), Convert.ToInt32(ddlAnio.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlMes.SelectedValue)),
                Indice = 0,
                Filas = Convert.ToInt16(ddlFilas.SelectedValue),
                Columna_ID = "PRQPED"
                //Filas = 10
            };

            // Carga las columnas en la lista desplegable del formulario de busqueda
            HerramientasASP.CargaNombreColumasDrop(ddlColumnas, ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).Dt);
            // Actualiza la vista de la GridView
            ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).ActualizarGdv(gdvRevision);
            // Muestra la cantidad de registros
            lblRegistros.Text = $"Registros: {(((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).Dt != null ? ((GridViewConfig)Session[_gdvRevisionNombre]).Dt.Rows.Count : 0)}";
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Y este es mi codigo de ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Boletas.aspx.cs" Inherits="NotificacionesV1._1.Boletas.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 align-items-center">
            <img src="../imagenes/note_102351.png" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 40px;" />
            <h4 class="d-inline"><%: Page.Title %></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--Barra divisora-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <!--Contenido principal-->
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlPrincipal" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExcel" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <%--Filtra por ubicación--%>
            <%--Ubicación--%>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlBusqueda" class="row">
                 
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12  pr-0">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-1 align-self-center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Operador:" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label><br/>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Año:" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label><br/>

                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Mes:" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
                            <asp:TextBox  ID="txtOperador" runat="server" placeholder="Operador" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" AutoPostBack="true" autofocus="true" ToolTip="Numero del operador"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" ID="ddlAnio" />
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" ID="ddlMes" />
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
                
                 <%--Consultar--%>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12  pt-1">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnConsultar" Text="Consultar" runat="server" CssClass=" btn btn-info" OnClick="bntConsultar_Click"/>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelError"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            
            <%--Formulario de busqueda del GV Detalle--%>
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                
                
            </div>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelResumen" class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12  pr-0">
                
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 form-inline">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilas" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFilas_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColumnas" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm ml-1">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBuscar" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="Buscar" OnClick="btnBuscar_Click" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-1" Text="Excel" OnClick="btnExcel_Click" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="text-primary ml-1 "></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRegistros" runat="server" CssClass="text-secondary ml-1 "></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </asp:Panel>
             

            <%--GridView D--%>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"> 
                    <asp:GridView ID="gdvRevision"
                                  AllowPaging="True" 
                                  AllowSorting="True" 
                                  BorderColor="#999999" 
                                  BorderStyle="Solid" 
                                  BorderWidth="1px" 
                                  CellPadding="3" 
                                  Font-Size="Small" 
                                  ForeColor="Black" 
                                  ridLines="Vertical"  
                                  OnPageIndexChanging="gdvRevision_PageIndexChanging" 
                                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="gdvRevision_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                  OnSorting="gdvRevision_Sorting" 
                                  OnRowCommand="gdvRevision_RowCommand" 
                                  OnRowDataBound="gdvRevision_RowDataBound" 
                                  PageSize="25" runat = "server" ShowFooter="True" style="width: 100%;"> 
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" CssClass="pagination-ys" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                       

                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <asp:Panel ID="panelViajes" runat="server">
                
                <%--GridView Detalle--%>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12"> 
                        <asp:GridView ID="gdvViajes" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"  PageSize="25" runat = "server" ShowFooter="True" style="width: 100%;"> 
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" CssClass="pagination-ys" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </asp:Panel>



        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    
    <!--Loading-->
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="upsVisorGuia" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="pnlPrincipal">
        <ProgressTemplate>1
            <div id="fondo"></div>
            <div id="progreso">
                <asp:Image ID="imgProgreso1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/loading-13.gif" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Tienes puesto el ScriptManager (creo que así se llamaba) ??

Comment: Si. El ScriptManager está cargado.